# Error in msg.value during online contract compilation

Tags: solidity, contract-development

I am getting this error while a contract compilation using online solidity compiler :

> Untitled:23:19: Error: Member "value" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in string storage pointer - did you
>   forget the "payable" modifier?
>         var amount = msg.value;
>                      ^-------^

Contract code is like this :

```
function transfer(address user) payable {
        var amount = msg.value;
        var sender = msg.sender;
```

What wrong i am doing ?

Comment: Nothing obviously wrong with this section. I got it to compile without issues by just wrapping it in `contract X {}`.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with it. What solidity compiler version you are using?

Comment: change the compiler and retry

Comment: I used solidity online solidity remix browser. I also tried to change the version, but error persisted. In one other contract , i used same but it was not throwing any error on remix browser. Don't know what is wrong

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: Yeah , i have added it below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error later. Nothing was wrong with the remix. I have declared a string with identifier as 'msg'. And it was the source of all the causes.